# Problem in Memoization part! Leetcode problem 121. Best Time to Buy and Sell Stock

Tags: python, dynamic-programming, memoization

I was trying to solve this problem, I know it can be done by one simple `for` loop but I wanna try doing it using `dp`.
So can anyone help in the memoization part?

### Problem:

You are given an array prices where `prices[i]` is the price of a given stock on the `i`th day.

You want to maximize your profit by choosing a single day to buy one stock and choosing a different day in the future to sell that stock.

Return the maximum profit you can achieve from this transaction. If you cannot achieve any profit, return 0.

### My solution

```py
class Solution:
    def maxProfit(self, prices: List[int]) -> int:
        n = len(prices)
        dp = [["abc"]*2**n for _ in range(n)]
        ans = 0
        i = 0
        def calc(index,buy):
            nonlocal ans,i
            # print(i)
            if index==n:
                return
            if buy!=-1:
                ans = max(ans,prices[index]-prices[buy])
                # print(ans,prices[index]-prices[buy])
                dp[buy][index]==prices[index]-prices[buy]
            i+=1
            if dp[index][index+1]=="abc":
                calc(index+1,index)
            if dp[buy][index+1]=="abc":
                calc(index+1,buy)
        calc(0,-1)
        print(i)
        return ans
```

Answer (score 0):

Please use proper syntax highlighting when inputting code.
Does this satisfy your needs?

```py
from typing import List
from functools import reduce

class Solution:
    def maxProfit(self, prices: List[int]) -> int:
        if not prices or len(prices) < 2:
            return 0

        def compute(acc, price):
            min_price, max_profit = acc
            min_price = min(min_price, price)
            current_profit = price - min_price
            max_profit = max(max_profit, current_profit)
            return (min_price, max_profit)

        _, max_profit = reduce(compute, prices, (prices[0], 0))

        return max_profit
```